# I can't launch my Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't launch my rails server. I googled a lot and i found no solution. I use windows 7. This is the problem:

rails s

```
> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:112:
in `routes': no such file to load -- action_dispatch/routing/route_set (LoadErro
r)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_con
troller/railtie.rb:62:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:25:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:49:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:134:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from D:/Facultate/Anul II/Sem 2/TW/RailsServiceTW/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/Facultate/Anul II/Sem 2/TW/RailsServiceTW/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
        from D:/Facultate/Anul II/Sem 2/TW/RailsServiceTW/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:
46:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:
46:in `initialize'
        from D:/Facultate/Anul II/Sem 2/TW/RailsServiceTW/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from D:/Facultate/Anul II/Sem 2/TW/RailsServiceTW/config.ru:1:in `<main>
'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:
35:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:
35:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:1
62:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:2
48:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:2
13:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/comman
ds/server.rb:65:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: refer following site http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/4/1/rails-3-0-second-beta-release

Comment: Seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696570/rails-app-not-starting-can-not-load-route-set

Answer (score 1):

try uninstall and reinstall actionpack

```
gem uninstall actionpack
gem install actionpack
```